# Why get textboxfor null exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

**Hey guys, I'm ASP.NET MVC beginner.
I practice according to the textbook example ASP.NET MVC
but got error!! It show null exception ...**

Controller :

```
namespace prjHelper.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Member member)
        {
            string msg = "";
            msg = $"註冊資料如下：<br>" +
               $"帳號：{member.UserId}<br>" +
               $"密碼：{member.Pwd}<br>" +
               $"姓名：{member.Name}<br>" +
               $"信箱：{member.Email}<br>" +
               $"生日：{member.BirthDay.ToShortDateString()}";
            ViewBag.Msg = msg;
            return View(member);
        }
    }
}
```

Model :

```
namespace prjHelper.Models
{
    public class Member
    {
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Pwd { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public DateTime BirthDay { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model prjHelper.Models.Member

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "會員註冊";
}

<h2>會員註冊</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>
        帳號：@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserId,  new { @class = "form-control", required="required"})
    </p>
    <p>
        密碼：@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Pwd,   new { @class = "form-control" })
    </p>
    <p>
        姓名：@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name,   new { @class = "form-control" })
    </p>
    <p>
        信箱：@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email,   new { @class = "form-control", type = "email" })
    </p>
    <p>
        生日：@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BirthDay,   new { @class = "form-control", type = "date" })
    </p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="註冊" class="btn btn-success" /></p>
    <hr />
    <p>@Html.Raw(@ViewBag.Msg)</p>
}
```

Can anybody explain it for me?
Thanks.

If you are doing your best, you will not have to worry about failure.
Energy and persistence conquer all things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You described the view data model as `@model prjHelper.Models.Member`. But in the `public ActionResult Create()` method you created `View()` without passing the data model. Therefore it's `null`.

You are defined the data model by using `@model`. It's called strongly typed view. Therefore it's necessary to create the `Memeber` object instance and pass it to the view like below:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    // Create the model that will be passed to the view for rendering.
    var model = new Member() { /* define properties */};

    // Now created `ViewResult` object for the response.
    return View(model);
}
```